# MySQL Query WHERE Including CASE or IF?

Tags: mysql, case, where-clause

Strange problem.

My Query looks like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, `etcetc`, `if/elses over muliple joined tables` FROM
    table1 AS `t1`
    # some joins, eventually unrelated in that context
WHERE
# some standard where statements, they work/

CASE 
    WHEN `t1`.`field` = "foo" THEN (`t1`.`anOtherField` != 123 AND `t1`.`anOtherField` != 456 AND `t1`.`anOtherOtherField` != "some String")
    WHEN `t1`.`field` = "bar" THEN `t1`.`aSecondOtherField` != 12345
    END

#ORDER BY CASE etc. Standard Stuff
```

Apperantly MySQL returns a wrong rowcount and I think my problem is in the logic of the WHERE ... CASE statement. Maybe with the brackets? Maybe I should go for operator `OR` and not `AND`? Should my the second `WHEN` include brackets also, even when I only compare one field? Should I use `IF` and not `CASE`?

Basically I want to exclude some rows with specific values IF theres a specific value in field `foo` or `bar`

I would try that all out, but it takes a huge amount of time to complete that query... :(

Edit: Just for the notes, my problem was, that I forgot the `ELSE` in my `CASE`.

```
CASE 
    WHEN `t1`.`field` = "foo" THEN (`t1`.`anOtherField` != 123 AND `t1`.`anOtherField` != 456 AND `t1`.`anOtherOtherField` != "some String")
    WHEN `t1`.`field` = "bar" THEN (`t1`.`aSecondOtherField` != 12345)
    ELSE TRUE
END
```

This solution works also, but the posted one is better...

Comment: This one is not the same as the solution below. ELSE TRUE -> OR (t1.field not in ('foo', 'bar'))

Comment: Yes, I know. I forgot to mention, that `t1`.`field` either can be an empty string (in that case no row should be returned) or some other string than 'foo' or 'bar' (in that case the row *should* be returned (+ some other field should be modified, its a complex qry)). Therefore I modified your solution to fit my needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use OR here instead of CASE:

```
WHERE
(`t1`.`field` = "foo" AND `t1`.`anOtherField` != 123 AND `t1`.`anOtherField` != 456 AND `t1`.`anOtherOtherField` != "some String")
OR
(`t1`.`field` = "bar" AND `t1`.`aSecondOtherField` != 12345)
```

Comment: Oh god, your right, im such a douchebag. Haha.

I clearly overdesigned that one, I was sure that it just could not be THAT easy and therefore didnt even thought about that solution entirely. Maybe happens when you write a page-long query.