# CASE in WHERE in mysql

Tags: mysql, case, where-clause

The question is as simple as the title says,But here is one logic.
Here is my code

```
CREATE TABLE `inf_brand_images` (
`id` bigint(99) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`brand` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`thumb` text NOT NULL,
`is_active` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`cmp_brand` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6458 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is data in this table

```
ID | brand  | thumb  |is_active| cmp_brand
1  | NIKE   | a.png  | 1       | 
2  | DUNHILL| b.png  | 1       |
3  | NIKE   | c.png  | 1       | 123_NIKE
4  | NIKE   | d.png  | 1       | 789_NIKE
```

cmp_brand is prefixed with some  their ids like 123_ and 789_ in my case.
Now if i search for NIKE, so I have two parameters,one is NIKE and other is id_NIKE.where id may be 123 or 456 or any other.

What i want is

```
IF cmp_brand is '' then compare with brand ELSE compare brand AND cmp_brand.
```

Here is what i tried

```
SELECT thumb 
FROM inf_brand_images 
where is_active=1  AND 
CASE WHEN cmp_brand = '' THEN brand='$brandname' 
ELSE cmp_brand='$id_$brandname' END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an OR in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as tot 
FROM inf_brand_images 
where is_active=1  AND 
((cmp_brand = '' AND brand='$brandname') OR (cmp_brand='$id_$brandname')
```

Possible duplicate:

- [MySQL Query WHERE Including CASE or IF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643783/mysql-query-where-including-case-or-if?rq=1)

Comment: It will give me more result?...What if i want to search thumb for '789_NIKE' in my above case?

Comment: This is not working for me  "SELECT thumb FROM inf_brand_images where is_active=1   AND 
((cmp_brand = '' AND brand='Gallery One') OR (cmp_brand='CMP_123_Gallery One'))"

Comment: You've edited your original question, and your comments do not make sense. Your last comment does not say what is not working so there is no way I can help you further. I would recommend creating a new question clearly explaining your problem, what you have tried, and what is not working.

Comment: Here i did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226766/case-in-where-clause-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IF` statement in your `WHERE` clause like so.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6118450/2/0

```
SELECT thumb 
  FROM inf 
 WHERE is_active=1
   AND 'nike' = IF(cmp_brand <>'', cmp_brand,brand)
```

You can also use a `CASE` statement to compute a value to be compared to another value in your `WHERE` clause, like so.

```
SELECT thumb
  FROM inf 
 WHERE is_active=1
   AND 'nike' =  
         CASE 
         WHEN (cmp_brand <> '') 
         THEN cmp_brand
         ELSE brand
          END
```